# how to clone custom search filter datatable (codeigniter)

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

So currently I have custom filter for datatable and the problem is I want to("Nah actually my product manager want to") make the custom filter to clone .The custom filter is already work perfectly and still figuring out to clone custom filter in datatable.

**View**

```
 <select class="form-control" id="searchStatus" style="background:#f2f2f2;color:#59595c;height:31px;">
                            <option value="">- Choose Status -</option>
                            <option values="1">1</option>
                            <option values="2">2</option>
   </select>
```

**jquery**

```
<script>
    // Custom Filter
        $('#searchStatus').on('change', function () {
                if (!!this.value) {
                    table.column(3).search(this.value).draw();
                } else {
                    table.column(3).search(this.value).draw();
                }
            } );
</script>
```

**Model**

```
         public function _get_custom_field(){
        if(isset($_POST['columns'][3]['search']['value'])){
           $this->db->where('status',$_POST['columns'][3]['search']['value']);
                    }
         }
```

"column(3)" is the number of column in my database that I need to filter.

Notice that the custom filter is already work.I'm still curious how to make it happen even I've googling it anywhere still can't find the answer.is it really possible to clone custom filter in datatable?

Comment: What do you mean by 'to clone'?

Comment: to Create a deep copy of the set of matched elements .like clone() in jquery [link](http://api.jquery.com/clone/)

Comment: like I will have another select box but filter the same data .and each filter will have different value